# IIS website publishing

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, ip

I'm running an ASP.NET web site through IIS from my computer.
I can access this website with ip address from my computer like `http://192.168.2.3:81/`
The question is how to access this website from other computers?

Comment: Please ask questions in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to open 81 port for your site in Windows Firewall on your computer so that you can access it from other computer.

Please refer [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

you can access the url within local system without any issues...but if you want to access your website remotely from other system then you must have to allow that port(here 81) in windows firewall...once that port is opened then other machines can able to access your application with that port...

For enabling port in windows firewall do the following steps

1.Start -> run -> wf.msc (Windows Firewall shortcut)

1. Goto inbound rules -> new rule

3.give the port number as per your requirement

4.Finish

5.Access your application across the world...Enjoy!!!

For complete reference follow the Microsoft official link below

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7